# How to use grouped rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group

Hello I have table with MultiIndex:

```
Lang                C++  java  python  All
Corp     Name                             
ASW      ASW        0.0   0.0     5.0    5
Facebook Facebook   8.0   1.0     5.0   14
Google   Google     2.0  24.0     1.0   27
ASW      Cristiano  NaN   NaN     5.0    5
Facebook Cristiano  NaN   NaN     3.0    3
         Michael    NaN   1.0     2.0    3
         Piter      8.0   NaN     NaN    8
Google   Cristiano  NaN   NaN     1.0    1
         Michael    NaN  24.0     NaN   24
         Piter      2.0   NaN     NaN    2
```

I am trying use this code

```
out = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda g: g.sort_values('All', ascending=False)
```

But It adds one more level index, how Can I use code without adding index?
I don't want to add and then delete indexes

thank You in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Add `group_keys=False` parameter in [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
out = (df.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False)
         .apply(lambda g: g.sort_values('All', ascending=False)))
print (out)
                    C++  java  python  All
Corp     Name                             
ASW      ASW        0.0   0.0     5.0    5
         Cristiano  NaN   NaN     5.0    5
Facebook Facebook   8.0   1.0     5.0   14
         Piter      8.0   NaN     NaN    8
         Cristiano  NaN   NaN     3.0    3
         Michael    NaN   1.0     2.0    3
Google   Google     2.0  24.0     1.0   27
         Michael    NaN  24.0     NaN   24
         Piter      2.0   NaN     NaN    2
         Cristiano  NaN   NaN     1.0    1
```

Better/faster/simplier solution is sorting by level of MultiIndex and column:

```
out = df.sort_values(['Corp','All'], ascending=[True, False])
print (out)
                    C++  java  python  All
Corp     Name                             
ASW      ASW        0.0   0.0     5.0    5
         Cristiano  NaN   NaN     5.0    5
Facebook Facebook   8.0   1.0     5.0   14
         Piter      8.0   NaN     NaN    8
         Cristiano  NaN   NaN     3.0    3
         Michael    NaN   1.0     2.0    3
Google   Google     2.0  24.0     1.0   27
         Michael    NaN  24.0     NaN   24
         Piter      2.0   NaN     NaN    2
         Cristiano  NaN   NaN     1.0    1
```

Comment: Thakn you! It works good, can you tell me how I Can insert row with sum of rows only with index level = 0?

Comment: @Abradab3 - like last row? then use `df.loc[('-','count 0')] = df.eq(0).sum()`

Comment: I would like to add a line at the end that counts values ​​only for (google, facebook, AWS) should looks: `Total :  10  25  11  46`